# Check if Cerberus is installed

Tags: applications

I bought a used Nexus 4 on a popular auction site. I have completely reflashed the rom using Googles stock images. I want to check if any security mechanism are installed, e.g. Cerberus. Will that be erased when reflashing the device? If not, how can I check if its installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cerberus will survive a Factory Reset if it was installed as a system app via root.

But nothing will survive flashing unless it infected the bootloader, which is hard enough that you can treat it as entirely improbable.